# iPad device orientation // interface orientation on application starting

Tags: xcode, ipad, orientation

We've an iPad application. It supports all the interface orientation.

It works perfectly, but after download the last version of the XCODE, 
 - when the application starts with didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
 - or execute the event applicationDidBecomeActive

Althought the device orientation was in landscape mode the interface turns always to the portrait mode.

It happens just the first time, after that point, when we rotate the device or the simulator, the application rotates successfully.

I search on the web, and found the next solution:
 - Create manually on the app-info.plist the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad node and include the four supported values.

```
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
```

But still doesn't works properly ...

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Ivan

Comment: If I check the device orientation is UIDeviceOrientationUnknown ... althought the     

[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
 has been executed previously

Answer (score 0):

In XCode, select the "project navigator" tab in the "navigator" panel, and click on the app name at the very top of the list. In the main editor area, you should see a list of targets on the left, select your main target. In the right side of the main editor, go to "summary", and choose your "Supported Device Orientations".

note: I am using Xcode 4.3 (this was true at least in 4.2 as well).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to AppDelegate

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];